How to trace the SSAS cube refresh failure details if we are refreshing the cube from a SQL Server Agent jobs
We have a tabular model cube that is refreshed each day via an SQL Agent job calling an SSAS Command. The command is simply:
{ "refresh": { "type": "full", "objects": [ { "database": "KPIDashboardv1" } ] } }

If the job fails, it will generate error message, but it is impossible to figure out which table was causing the refresh failure.
Please help me with the way how can we get the detailed error message which says the exact table name causing the refresh failure.
SQL Agent Job Error Message looks like :
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaException: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForSoapFault(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForError(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessageAndReturnResult(String& result, Boolean skipResult)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.ExecuteStatement(String statement, String properties, String& result, Boolean skipResult, Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.Execute(String command, String properties, String& result, Boolean skipResult, Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.ExecuteStatement(String stmt, StatementType stmtType, Boolean withResults, String properties, String parameters, Boolean restrictionListElement, String discoverType, String catalog)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.SendCommand(String command, Boolean withResults, String properties)
   at OlapEvent(SCH_STEP* pStep, SUBSYSTEM* pSubSystem, SUBSYSTEMPARAMS* pSubSystemParams, Boolean fQueryFlag)Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaException: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00; Unknown token received from SQL Server; HY000.

   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForSoapFault(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForError(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessageAndReturnResult(String& result, Boolean skipResult)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.ExecuteStatement(String statement, String properties, String& result, Boolean skipResult, Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.Execute(String command, String properties, String& result, Boolean skipResult, Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.ExecuteStatement(String stmt, StatementType stmtType, Boolean withResults, String properties, String parameters, Boolean restrictionListElement, String discoverType, String catalog)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.SendCommand(String command, Boolean withResults, String properties)
   at OlapEvent(SCH_STEP* pStep, SUBSYSTEM* pSubSystem, SUBSYSTEMPARAMS* pSubSystemParams, Boolean fQueryFlag)Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaException: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00; Unknown token received from SQL Server; HY000.

   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForSoapFault(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForError(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessageAndReturnResult(String& result, Boolean skipResult)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.ExecuteStatement(String statement, String properties, String& result, Boolean skipResult, Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.Execute(String command, String properties, String& result, Boolean skipResult, Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.ExecuteStatement(String stmt, StatementType stmtType, Boolean withResults, String properties, String parameters, Boolean restrictionListElement, String discoverType, String catalog)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.SendCommand(String command, Boolean withResults, String properties)
   at OlapEvent(SCH_STEP* pStep, SUBSYSTEM* pSubSystem, SUBSYSTEMPARAMS* pSubSystemParams, Boolean fQueryFlag)Job 'PKG_MIB_DLY'


I suggest that you try directly refreshing the table from the server ( not using sql agent) This is the easiest way to see which table is causing the problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
